# How to set scopes for accesing list of excelsheets of google drive in php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to list the excel files from google drive. For this I am using the DRIVE API [Quickstart Guid](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php). But having errors. Mentioned below:

```
**define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
));

//Scopes authorized client object

$client = getClient();

// code to print the names and id up to 10 files.

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
//$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 

$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)');
//$file = new Google_Service_Sheets($client); 
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
  print "No files found.\n";
} else {
  print "Files:\n";
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
  }
}**
```

Notice: Undefined property: Google_Service_Sheets::$files in C:\xampp\htdocs\today\quickstart.php on line 82

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listFiles() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\today\quickstart.php:82 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\today\quickstart.php on line 82

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this document - [Retrieve a list of spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/worksheets#retrieve_a_list_of_spreadsheets)

> The Google Sheets API supports fetching a list of spreadsheets for the authenticated user. Note however that you cannot create or delete spreadsheets via this API.
>
> You can request a feed containing a list of the currently authenticated user's spreadsheets by sending an authenticated **`GET`** request to the following URL:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
```

OR

Use [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) (Drive API)

> `mimeType  string  contains, =, != MIME type of the file.`
>
> Search for folders using the folder-specific MIME type
>
> `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`

Here is a sample code:

```
$pageToken = null;
do {
  $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array(
    'q' => "mimeType='image/jpeg'",
    'spaces' => 'drive',
    'pageToken' => $pageToken,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, items(id, title)',
  ));
  foreach ($response->items as $file) {
      printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
  }
} while ($pageToken != null);
```

**Note**: you've link a Sheets API quickstart and not Drive API quickstart, here is the link for the [quickstart for Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Robot.

Comment: But when I try it with another google id. It listed the previously google account's sheets listing. How it will work for the current logged in gmail-ID. If user used the same link with their own google id. The app will show their own sheets by authentication.